# Defining listener on web navigation on pages declared by user aka How to define mutable host in background.js?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I've created chrome extension that is sending post request with information about specific url that is currently browsed by user to flask (local host) and then some web scraping on this url is done and based on the obtained information and excel file that user uploads (when there is necessity of uploading its content) to the server a specific category is assigned. After this process is done there is a popup that shows that category. How can I make host/url mutable based on user needs? --> Ideally, i would like the user to be responsible for defining the url e.g by uploading a txt/excel with file this information. This information must be somehow transferred to background.js in these fields hostEquals,urlPrefix and urlMatches, but i have no clue what to do to make this work (maybe sth with native messaging between content.js and background.js or injecting SQL into background.js?). Below please find the the code of relevant parts (I know that there might be a lot of unnecessary stuff but I am still a newbie).

Chrome extension parts 
(now url is set to stack as example but it works on every host I define earlier in the background)

**background.js**

```
function onCommit(info) {
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/background',true);
xhr.send(info.url);
xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log('onload %d:%d', info.tabId, info.frameId, info.url);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  };
};
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(onCommit, {
url: [
{hostEquals: 'www.stackoverflow.com'}, //<--how to replace that part?
{urlPrefix: 'https://stackoverflow.com/'},//<-- as above
{urlMatches: '^https://(www\\.)?stackoverflow.com/.*$'}//<--as above,
],
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Whatever",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Whatever",
"permissions": ["webNavigation",
"tabs","activeTab"],
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_title": "Fetch active url"
},
"background": {
        "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

and python/flask parts

**flaskscript.py**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask_cors import CORS
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgresql://postgres:postgreqwerty@localhost/database'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
CORS(app)

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgreqwerty@localhost/database')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        df = pd.read_excel(request.files.get('file'))
        dataframe=pd.DataFrame(df)
        dataframe.to_sql ('database', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
        return render_template('upload.html', data=dataframe.to_html(header=True,classes="table table-striped"))
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/background',methods=['GET','POST'])
def background():
    data = str(request.data).replace("b'","'")
    data=data[1:-1]
    page=requests.get(data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup (page.content, "html.parser")
```

[etc. - generally webscraping, and returning a category assigned by specific conditions which is shown in extension popup when user is on defined pages]

**upload.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
Data is: {{ data| safe}}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After leaving it for some time and some more research on JS i managed to do it. JS part:

```
let resp=''
function onCommit(info) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/background',true);
    xhr.send(info.url);
    xhr.onload = () =>  {alert(xhr.responseText)};
};
const xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/get", true);
xhr2.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr2.readyState == 4) {
    resp = xhr2.responseText;
    console.log(resp);
    chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(onCommit, {url : [{urlPrefix: resp}]}) // here may be whatever you need according to: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation (onCommited section) eg. hostContains etc
      };
    }
    xhr2.send();
    console.log("string xhr send")
```

Still don't know if it is optimal, but it is working now. Ofc i needed to create another route in flask that handle GET response.